# How to prevent histograms from overlaying (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to plot two separate histogram plots however python is overlaying the two and I am not sure why?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.uniform(0, 1.0, 1000)
(count, bins, ignored) = plt.hist(points, bins = 50, density = True)

fourpointlist = []

for count in range(0, 100):
    fourpoints = np.random.normal(0, 1, 32)
    fourpointlist.append(np.average(fourpoints))

(count, bins, ignored) = plt.hist(fourpointlist, bins = 50, density = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.uniform(0, 1.0, 1000)

plt.figure() #Creates a new figure
(count, bins, ignored) = plt.hist(points, bins = 50, density = True)

fourpointlist = []
for count in range(0, 100):
    fourpoints = np.random.normal(0, 1, 32)
    fourpointlist.append(np.average(fourpoints))


plt.figure() #Creates a new figure
(count, bins, ignored) = plt.hist(fourpointlist, bins = 50, density = True)
plt.show()
```

**Output (generates two separate plots)**:

[image]

[image]